# Why can't I install PyQt5 from the pypi?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pycharm

I want to use PyQt5 in pycharm. After trying to install the package from Available packages, an error says: 'Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package PyQt5.'
The complete log is here:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.0.1\helpers\packaging_tool.py run on 02/05/14 16:13:23
Downloading/unpacking PyQt5

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt5/
  URLs to search for versions for PyQt5:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt5/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt5/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyQt5

No distributions at all found for PyQt5

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 266, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1026, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\pip\index.py", line 171, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for PyQt5
```

What should I do?

This is what I've done is this:

- Installed Python 3.3 and added to PATH
- Installed `PyQt5-5.2-gpl-Py3.3-Qt5.2.0-x64.exe`

And I don't know how to use `PyQt` in pycharm.
can you provide more information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot install PyQt4/PyQt5 from PyPI. You would have to install it separately.

If you see [this](https://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt5/) link, you can see that there are no listed packages for PyQt5 (likewise for PyQt4) on PyPI. So, you would need to download the installer separately from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) and install it.

That is what the

> DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for PyQt5

refers to.

[UPDATE]: You'll also most likely need to install sip the same way, here's how: https://askubuntu.com/a/666336/12214

Comment: I'm sorry, I have not used PyCharm before, so cannot provide any suggestions to you on that.

Comment: Which IDE you prefer? Tell me the name and if poddible, tell me how to install pyqt in that IDE. I just want to use pyqt. IDE no important.

Comment: Anyway, just install PyQt4 on your system and you can use the Eclipse IDE. Just convince yourself that it is going to work without the need to do anything else :-)

Comment: I think I've installed PyQt on my system(Windows 8) but When in pycharm I'm trying to use the library, It says there is no lib called PyQt! how can I find that whether it's installed on my system or not?

Comment: From the Python interpreter, do a `import PyQt4`. It will throw an error if it's not installed.

Comment: I don't use any IDE. Just a text editor and Python interpreter is enough. Atom on Windows and Vim on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, installing QtPy5 with pip works in 3.6.5. According to https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download even 3.5 and later.