# How to build PyQt5 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, c++, linux, ubuntu, pyqt

I'm trying to move my work from `PySide` to `PyQt5`.

My project works with `Python3.4.1` yet Ubuntu's default python3 is `Python3.4.0`, So I have to compile `PyQt5` by myself.

`Python3.4.1`'s path is `/opt/python3.4.1/bin/python3.4` and it works well

my system is ubuntu14.04

---

First, I download the source from official site, `PyQt-gpl-5.3.1.tar.gz` and `sip-4.16.2.tar.gz`.
Sip was installed successfully while an error occurs with making `pyqt`.

my command is:

```
$/opt/python3.4.1/bin/python3.4 configure.py
$make
```

and the erro is

> g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -shared -o libpyqt5qmlplugin.so pluginloader.o moc_pluginloader.o  -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/opt/python3.4.1/lib -lpython3.4m -lQt5Qml -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /opt/python3.4.1/lib/libpython3.4m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>
> /opt/python3.4.1/lib/libpython3.4m.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[1](http://pyside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/building/linux.html): *** [libpyqt5qmlplugin.so] Error 1

The error do not raise when I use the default `$python3 configure.py` and looks quite similar to an error when I build PySide(it is fixed by [this](http://pyside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/building/linux.html)). But I am weak in compiling so I can't fix pyqt like they do with pyside.

I also tried `pip install PyQt5` in my `virtualenv`, unfortunately, got the same failure like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577723/can-not-install-pyqt5-from-the-python-packaging-index).

Even the successful build (looks like) with default python, two error shows when running.

1. the default install path is "site-packages", which is instead of "dist-packages" on ubuntu.
   So I have to change my PYTHONPATH by myself.
2. which is the most annoying problem, when I import it:

   > from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

   an error occurs :

   > Traceback (most recent call last):
   >   File "", line 1, in 
   >    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
   >   RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v11.1

All the source is the latest released on the official site ! Is that a joke?

---

Finally, I use `apt-get install python3-pyqt5` to install pyqt to my default python3.4.0. It works well now, and I still can't find a way to build a PyQt for python3.4.1.

Comment: The questions might have attracted more interest on askubuntu, a sister site of SO, seeing that there are no answers from others here. But since you already provided and answer which seems to work, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks, I will go and search for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really a hard work!

> /usr/bin/ld: /opt/python3.4.1/lib/libpython3.4m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

This error raise because the linker could not find `libpythonX.X.so`.
When I built my `Python3.4.1`, I used only one option`--prefix`, so I do not have a shared lib in my python's lib.

Then I rebuild my python with `--enable-shared`, then install `PyQt5`, and successfully import PyQt.

However, I realize my python version is 3.4.0! Python exec. was linked to system python's lib...

This article helps me a lot: http://koansys.com/tech/building-python-with-enable-shared-in-non-standard-location

Finally, I add `LDFLAGS= -Wl,-rpath /opt/python3.4.1/lib` to configure option:

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.4.1 --enable-shared  LDFLAGS= -Wl,-rpath /opt/python3.4.1/lib

and then installed PyQt5.

Now, I can enjoy it~(≧▽≦)/~